# Disappearing ACF field reference on non-imported field after running an import with WP All Import

Tags: wordpress, import, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

So here is my setup, we have a custom post type (products) that uses ACF fields. We import the content for this custom post type using WP All Import from an in-house API.

The field in question is a Repeater field and is excluded from and explicitly ignored in the import I setup for this. I did this in the import settings of the specific import by checking "Update existing products with changed data in your file." Under that I have "Advanced Custom Fields" checked. Under that, I have "Leave these ACF fields alone, update all other ACF fields". And under that, I have my ACF field and all the fields under it included.

These items are excluded because we want to manually enter the information via the CMS admin.

When I run the import everything looks fine. But when I load the products that have this repeater field filled out it loads nothing on the product page. If I load the edit page for this product in admin, the information is still there. When I hit save and then revisit the product page the data shows up again.

*Doing some digging today with xDebug, I found that the reference to the field for this post ID in wp_postmeta goes away. BUT the reference to the fields within the Repeater field still exists. So it is just this parent Repeater field that seems to be the problem. All of these are in that exclude list mentioned above.*

**We are using the following plugins that are related to this:**

- Advanced Custom Fields PRO (5.8.11)
- WP All Import Pro (4.6.1)
- WP All Import - ACF Add-On (3.2.6)

We also have Yoast SEO and other plugins installed, but seem unrelated to this. I will mention that Yoast fields are set to ignore and don't seem to have a problem. I am also running Wordpress 5.4.2.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix it? I am at a loss right now.

Comment: Hard to say without digging into the code. You're using the WP All Import Pro so you have access to their dedicated support - try asking your question directly at https://www.wpallimport.com/support